# redirect_uri_mismatch when using identity launchWebAuthFlow for google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-oauth

I've been trying to get chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow work with my Chrome Extension to access Google's OAuth Flow (no, I prefer not to use the getAuthToken). I've followed the implementation [layed out in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40411493/can-chrome-identity-launchwebauthflow-be-used-to-authenticate-against-google-api).

These are the steps I went through to set things up:

1. Generated a Key for my Extension that I've added to manifest.json, so the Extension ID doesn't change (according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497781/how-to-change-chrome-packaged-app-id-or-why-do-we-need-key-field-in-the-manifest/21500707#21500707))
2. Went to to Google Cloud Platform and registered a new Application and enabled the API access. For Credentials I chose OAuth ID > Chrome App, entered my Extension ID and got my client ID.
3. I've implemented this code in my background.js file

   ```
   var auth_url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth';
   var client_id = '<client_id from Cloud Console>';
   var redirect_url = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL("oauth2");
   var auth_params = {
       client_id: client_id,
       redirect_uri: redirect_url,
       response_type: 'token',
       scope: 'profile'
   };

   var params = Object.keys(auth_params).map(function(k) {
       return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(auth_params[k])}).join('&')
   auth_url += '?' + params;

   console.log(redirect_url);
   console.log(auth_url);
   chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({url: auth_url, interactive: true}, 
           function(responseUrl) { console.log(responseUrl); });
   ```

When I run this I receive
`Unchecked runtime.lastError while running identity.launchWebAuthFlow: Authorization page could not be loaded.`

Then I check the auth URL in the browser and the error is 400 redirect_uri_mismatch

Now I've checked the redirect_url countless times. It is of the format       `https://<app-id>.chromiumapp.org/oauth2` - The App ID matches exactly what I put into the Cloud Console Credentials. It also doesn't change when I reload the Extension, as it is tied to the Key in the manifest.json

What am I missing? Can anyone confirm that this still works?

For reference, my manifest.json file

```
    {
      "name": "My OAuth Extension",
      "key": "<My KEY>",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "description": "Testing OAuth",
      "homepage_url": "http://test.com",
      "default_locale": "en",
      "permissions": [
        "https://*/*",
        "identity",
        "*://*.google.com/*"
      ],
      "background": {
        "scripts": ["src/bg/background.js"],
        "persistent": true
      }
    }
```

What am I missing? Can anyone confirm that this still works?

Comment: were you able to figure this out? I'm working on the same problem.

Comment: no, I ended up using a workaround with whereas firebase auth takes over the authentication via oauth

Answer (score 4):

I had an identical project in my application and solved it as follows:

1. I created a new ClientID of type Web application in Google Cloud Platform
2. I added the following url to the Authorized redirect URIs: `https://<appId>.chromiumapp.org/`.
3. I used the new ClientID in the `url` argument in the `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow` function.
4. After sign in I got `redirect_url` in the function callback.