# chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow with Chrome Extension OAuth 2.0 Client ID leads to Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, supabase

I am trying to log users into my Chrome extension with `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow`, yet I keep getting the following error: `Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch` (see screenshot below).

**Context**

- I use Google Workspace and the extension is private to my domain
- I have created a dedicated OAuth 2.0 Client ID of type "Chrome Extension" in the Google Cloud console Credentials, and have verified app ownership
- I try to authenticate using the code below - I have double checked that the extension ID matches the redirect URI
- My intention is to use the Google token to [log users into Supabase](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/social-login/auth-google?platform=chrome-extensions)

```js
function login() {
  const manifest = chrome.runtime.getManifest();
  if (!manifest.oauth2?.scopes) throw new Error('No OAuth2 scopes defined in the manifest file');

  const url = new URL('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth');

  url.searchParams.set('client_id', manifest.oauth2.client_id);
  url.searchParams.set('response_type', 'id_token');
  url.searchParams.set('access_type', 'offline');
  url.searchParams.set('redirect_uri', `https://${chrome.runtime.id}.chromiumapp.org`);
  url.searchParams.set('scope', manifest.oauth2.scopes.join(' '));

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
      {
        url: url.href,
        interactive: true,
      },
      async (redirectedTo) => {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
              reject(`Could not login - ${chrome.runtime.lastError.message}`);
        } else {
          const url = new URL(redirectedTo!);
          const params = new URLSearchParams(url.hash);
          resolve(params.get('id_token'))
        }
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": ["identity", ...],
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "<client ID>",
    "scopes": ["openid", "email", "profile"]
  },
  ...
}
```

**What else I have tried**

- For redirect_uri, in addition to the code above, I have also tried `chrome.identity.getRedirectURL()` and `chrome.identity.getRedirectURL('oauth2')`, all leading to the same result
- I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52903191/redirect-uri-mismatch-when-using-identity-launchwebauthflow-for-google-chrome-ex) - use a "Web application" client ID instead of a "Chrome extension" client ID, and add the redirect URL to the list of Authorized redirect URIs - still leads to the same result

What am I missing?

[image: Screenshot of Oauth error]

Answer (score 0):

All right I made it work with these three changes:

1. I used a Client ID for **Web application** rather than for Chrome extension and added https://<extension_id>.chromiumapp.org (**without** trailing slash) to the list of Authorized redirect URIs
2. To make this work locally, I added the [manifest key](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/manifest/key) to my extension - Google seems to check the extension ID at runtime as part of `launchWebAuthFlow`
3. I replaced `const params = new URLSearchParams(url.hash)` with `const params = new URLSearchParams(url.hash.replace('#', ''))`. The reason is `url.hash` looks like `#id_token=<id_token>&...`, so the search param key looks like `%23id_token` and `params.get('id_token')` returns `undefined`.

Hope this helps