# chrome.identity.getAuthToken not supported

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have followed the [tutorial in the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/tut_oauth/) for Google authentication of a user from my Chrome extension written in React.

Since the tutorial is not for React, I had to adjust the way of calling `chrome.identity.getAuthToken`. I have put the call to `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` into `useEffect` in my `App` component:

```js
function App() {
    useEffect(
        () => {
            console.log('chrome', chrome)
            console.log('chrome.identity', chrome.identity)
            console.log('chrome.identity.getAuthToken', chrome.identity.getAuthToken)
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
            chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true}, function(token) {
                console.log('Token:', token);
            });
        },
        []
    )
    return (
        ... // Stuff unrelated to authentication, renders without a problem
    );
}
```

The output in the console is:

[image]

So, the function `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` is defined, but is *not supported*. What does "not supported" mean? What could I be missing?

Comment: Quick googling reveals it can happen in the Opera browser which doesn't implement this function.

Comment: @wOxxOm It did not come up in my searches, but yes, I am using Opera. I'll install Chrome just to check whether it works there and update. In the meanwhile, how do I modify my code, so that my Chrome extension is usable in Opera as well?

Comment: @wOxxOm You are right. It works in Chrome.

Comment: @wOxxOm I posted the workaround I found as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment of @wOxxOm, the problem is that `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` is not supported by Opera.

The workaround for Opera that worked was to use `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow`.

[The linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56304540/2725810) provides an example of usage. Make sure to read carefully the comments in that example.