# How to access Google Drive API from Chrome extension running on non-Chrome browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have made a Chrome extension that successfully accesses the Google Drive API. It does so by employing access tokens like so...

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, (accessToken) => {
    sendResponse({ type: MESSAGE_PROTOCOL.AUTH_RESPONSE, accessToken });
```

...however, when I try and run the code on other Chrome-based browsers like Edge it appears that chrome.identity.getAuthToken is not available. After much Googling it seems that there is an alternative (involving launchWebAuthFlow) but I can not find a complete worked example, only little snippets and clues which I am not expert enough to convert into a solution. Surely there must be a complete example somewhere.

A worked example for a different Google API would probably be fine too.

**EDIT:** I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40411493/can-chrome-identity-launchwebauthflow-be-used-to-authenticate-against-google-api) which is probably pretty close to what I am after though so far I have failed to get any of the answers to work. I notice that the top voted answer to that question was for manifest v2 and I'm not sure whether the answer will be valid for v3. Can anyone confirm? Also the code contains a comment with "(Must be Web Application)" which is extra confusing.

**EDIT:** Just to be clear, I don't have my own server, I want the whole process to be handled by the extension itself.

**EDIT:** If anyone knows of an existing extension that accesses a Google API, can work on Edge, uses manifest v3, is not compressed/obfuscated and does not rely on its own server then I could examine the code myself and that should do the trick.

**EDIT:** Following on from suggestions here and elsewhere I am now of the opinion that a key part of getting this to work is not just the code to be executed in the app but also exactly how set up the google cloud console to correctly correspond to it, particularly the redirect-URI.

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting "`Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch`".
> I have made a file `oauth2callback.html` which I put in the root directory of my extension. The manifest includes `"redirect_uri": "oauth2callback.html"` immediately after the scopes list.

That error should mean there is a mismatch between the redirect URI specified in the OAuth2 request and the one registered in the Google Cloud Console for the OAuth2 client ID.
See "[Obtaining OAuth 2.0 access tokens / Redirect to Google's OAuth 2.0 server](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow#oauth-2.0-endpoints)".

> My software is a chrome extension.

Chrome Extensions have a different flow for handling OAuth 2.0 authentication, and they do not require manual configuration of redirect URIs in the Google Cloud Console as web applications do. The redirect URI for a Chrome extension is derived from the extension's ID and is automatically constructed as `https://<extension-id>.chromiumapp.org/`.

In the `background.js` script, the `redirect_uri` parameter should be obtained using `chrome.identity.getRedirectURL()` method without any arguments:

```js
'&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(chrome.identity.getRedirectURL())
```

That will automatically generate the correct redirect URI based on the extension's ID.

Then make sure the `client_id` specified in the `manifest.json` file and the `background.js` script corresponds to the OAuth 2.0 client ID generated in the Google Cloud Console for the Chrome Extension.

And check that the permissions in the `manifest.json` file include `"identity"` and the correct API scope for Google Drive:

```json
"permissions": [
      "identity",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/*"
],
"oauth2": {
      "client_id": "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
      "scopes": [
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"
      ]
}
```

Just in case, check that the OAuth consent screen configuration in the Google Cloud Console is correctly set up, including the application name, support email, and other necessary details.

Load the extension in Chrome (or a Chromium-based browser), check that there are errors in the console, and test the OAuth 2.0 flow again.

---

> Putting `https://www.googleapis.com/*` in the permissions list leads to `... https:/ /www.googleapis.com/* is unknown or URL pattern is malformed`.

That should mean the specified URL pattern in the permissions list is not recognized or formatted incorrectly.

Instead of specifying the wildcard URL `https://www.googleapis.com/*` under the "`permissions`" field, specify the required Google Drive API scope under the ["`oauth2`" field's "`scopes`" array](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/app_identity/#update_manifest) in the `manifest.json` file of your extension:

````json
```json
"oauth2": {
    "client_id": "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
    "scopes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"
    ]
}
````

And make sure the "identity" permission remains in the "permissions" field to enable OAuth 2.0 flow:

```json
"permissions": [
    "identity"
]
```

So something like:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Your Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "identity"
  ],
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"
    ]
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

Reload your extension in Chrome or a Chromium-based browser, and test again the OAuth 2.0 authentication flow.

---

> Following on from suggestions here and elsewhere I am now of the opinion that a key part of getting this to work is not just the code to be executed in the app but also exactly how set up the google cloud console to correctly correspond to it, particularly the redirect-URI.

True: The setup on the Google Cloud Console is crucial for the OAuth 2.0 flow to work correctly.
The `redirect_uri` specified in the OAuth 2.0 request must match exactly with one of the redirect URIs registered in the Google Cloud Console for the OAuth 2.0 client ID being used. That is a security measure to make sure the OAuth 2.0 responses are sent only to authorized URIs.

---

Current finding from [the discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56779325#56779325):

> My current suspicion is that there is some kind of human error at Google - the process of getting my app to have the "verified" status took weeks and clearly involved an actual human being at Google to tick some box somewhere.
>
> Now that I have manually added a client ID as a web-app after having previously declared the thing to be a Chrome extension has somehow fallen between the cracks in the verification process and I may be blocked from getting this to work unless a human at Google takes some action.

Comment: I do not see any "Authorized redirect URIs" section in the OAuth consent screen page.

Comment: @Mick it  should be in the "Credentials" page rather than the "OAuth consent screen" page in the Google Cloud Console.

Comment: not there either... Just a hunch, is this something to do with web-apps? My software is a chrome extension.

Comment: @Mick Probably, as I was reading from "[Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#creatingcred)".

Comment: @Mick I have edited the answer to address the Chrome extension use case.

Comment: Putting ``https://www.googleapis.com/*`` in the permissions list leads to ... ``https:/ /www.googleapis.com/*`` is unknown or URL pattern is malformed. I think your answer is getting a bit messy because the bulk of it is addressing web-apps with chrome extensions being a kind of correction to the rest of it. The question is specifically about extensions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255614/discussion-between-vonc-and-mick).

Answer (score 0):

`chrome.identity.getAuthToken` method is specific to Chrome

Use `launchWebAuthFlow` method, which is supported in both Chrome and non-Chrome browsers.

Example:

```
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
  url: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>&response_type=token&redirect_uri=<YOUR_REDIRECT_URI>&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
  interactive: true
}, (redirectUrl) => {
  const accessToken = redirectUrl.match(/access_token=([^&]+)/)[1];
  sendResponse({ type: MESSAGE_PROTOCOL.AUTH_RESPONSE, accessToken });
});
```

Here, you need to replace <YOUR_CLIENT_ID> and <YOUR_REDIRECT_URI> specified in your Google Cloud Console project.

Note* *The chrome.identity.getAuthToken method, which is used to obtain access tokens, is not available in non-Chrome browsers.*

Comment: Re: "Here, you need to replace <YOUR_CLIENT_ID> and <YOUR_REDIRECT_URI> specified in your Google Cloud Console project."... as far as I can tell there is no way to specify a redirect URI in the google cloud console for a chrome extension.